# this.props.location return undefined when I add query

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need adding a query like `mobile=true` to url to get a slightly modified page. When adding the following code in App.js `const mobileAp = location.search.indexOf("mobile=true") > -1;`, everything works out well. But when I try to get the URL in another module using an identical method, but he return `Cannot read property 'search' of undefined`. When I follow the link without an additional parameter, everything works fine. Tell me, please, what could be the matter?

I tried to copy all the states, import all the modules available in the App.js, but this did not work...

Comment: Share the code where its not working

Comment: @Anil Kurmar about 350 lines in each of them, nobody will kill me for it?

Comment: Just check where its not working...if component is wrapped with withRouter. If not wrap it with withRouter.

Comment: could you not be more precise please, i need to wrap only a variable, or a whole class? sorry for my stupidity

Comment: export default withRouter(component). I mean whole class or function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand what the problem was.

using the following code, I was finally able to obtain the necessary data and saved myself from torture

```
query: T.shape({
        mobile: T.bool.isRequired
        }).isRequired
const test = get(this.props, 'location.query.mobile');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
.... 
....
export default withRouter(YourComponent) // Component that needs access to location
```